# dummyVars producing NA values in output

Tags: r, r-caret, dummy-variable

I have used `dummyVars` function from `Caret` package before to make dummy variables out of characters/factors with also missing values `(NA)` and it worked successfully.

This time, however, the output I get includes `NA` values. The default is that it treats `NA` also as a separate entry and makes a dummy variable for it as well. Am I missing something? More worried because it worked last time with `NA` values.

Using the following code:

```
dum = dummyVars("~.",data = char_data_raw_train)
char_data_raw_train_dum = predict(dum, newdata = char_data_raw_train)
```

The output file, i.e. `char_data_raw_train_dum` includes `NA`s. Please help.

Comment: What version of the `caret` package have you used "last time"?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have `NA` as a separate level of a one-hot encoded variable from `dummyVars`, you could use `?addNA` to explicitly define it as level. Here's a small example:

```
d <- mtcars[,(1:3)]
d$cyl <- factor(d$cyl)
# set some entries to NA
d$cyl[c(1,5,10,15,20)] <- NA 
# explicitly define NA as level
d$cyl <- addNA(d$cyl)
library(caret)
data.frame(predict(dummyVars(data = d, formula = ~.), d))

                     mpg cyl.4 cyl.6 cyl.8 cyl.NA  disp
Mazda RX4           21.0     0     0     0      1 160.0
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0     0     1     0      0 160.0
Datsun 710          22.8     1     0     0      0 108.0
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4     0     1     0      0 258.0
Hornet Sportabout   18.7     0     0     0      1 360.0
Valiant             18.1     0     1     0      0 225.0
[...]
```